# string definition problem

Tags: string, function

```
int main() 
{ 
    int score; 
    string scoreLetter; 
    char A, B, C, D, F; 

    cout<<"Enter the grade: "; 
    cin>> score; 

    void letterGrade (int score); 
    void gradeFinal (int score); 

    cout<<"The letter grade is "<< scoreLetter<<"."; 
} 

void letterGrade (int score) 
{ 
    if (score >= 90) { 
        string scoreLetter = 'A'
    } else if (score >= 80) { 
        scoreLetter = 'B'
    } else if (score >= 70)
```

-When compiling, I am getting an error for the line scoreLetter = 'A', etc. What is wrong with this? Error states 'scoreLetter' undefined. Do I need to define scoreLetter in the function not the main?

Comment: You do realize a part of your code is missing, right?

Comment: If you're referring to my return 0; no, I didnt realize that until just now. however, I only posted the segment of code that appears to be the issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to return whatever value your function determines `scoreLetter` should be, and in `main` have a line like `scoreLetter = letterGrade(score);`.  You can't set local variables from another function, unless the caller passed them to you by reference, which isn't happening here (and, in most cases, shouldn't be abused like that).

Aside from that, it looks like you're mixing up declarations and invocations.  `void letterGrade (int score);` doesn't actually call `letterGrade`; it just says that there *is* a `letterGrade` function that takes an int, which we'll call "score".  (The `score` there is just a name that's part of the prototype; it has no connection to your `score` variable.)  So you'll likely find that if you managed to get your code to compile, it'd do something quite different than you're expecting it to do.

To call a function, you'd do something like `letterGrade(score);`, or if you followed my first suggestion, `scoreLetter = letterGrade(score);`.

```
string letterGrade (int score); 
// void gradeFinal (int score);  // not used in this snippet

int main() 
{ 
    int score; 
    string scoreLetter; 
    char A, B, C, D, F; 

    cout<<"Enter the grade: "; 
    cin>> score; 

    scoreLetter = letterGrade(score);

    cout<<"The letter grade is "<< scoreLetter<<"."; 
} 

string letterGrade (int score) 
{
    string grade;
    if (score >= 90) { 
        grade = "A";
    } else if (score >= 80) { 
        grade = "B";
    } else if (score >= 70)

    ...

    return grade;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes in C/C++ are used to define a character, not a String. Use double quotes instead. `string scoreLetter = "A"`. Also you need to include the header if `std::string` is what you are trying to use: `#include <string>` and `using std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is cut off there but I think from what is available you are not calling the functions properly.

You should also try to be more specific about what language you are talking about, i.e. C in this case I believe.

A correct call to the functions would be:

letterGrade(score);

And yes, you need to define the string variable at global scope, so just move it out of main and above it.

```
    string scoreLetter; 
    int main() 
{ 
    int score; 
    char A, B, C, D, F; 

    cout<<"Enter the grade: "; 
    cin>> score; 

    letterGrade (score); 
    gradeFinal (score); 

    cout<<"The letter grade is "<< scoreLetter<<"."; 
} 

void letterGrade (int score) 
{ 
    if (score >= 90) { 
        scoreLetter = "A"
    } else if (score >= 80) { 
        scoreLetter = "B"
    } else if (score >= 70)
```

Comment: that would be the fast workaround for getting the code to compile. even though i don't use c at all, what i would do is make the function return a string, i.e. void letterGrade --> string letterGrade and replace the scoreLetter = "A" etc by return "A" ...

Comment: And it's C++ -- C doesn't have `cin` and `cout`.

Comment: Thank you, sorry about that, I meant to say it was c++. I need to assign scoreLetter to "A", as I will then be running an if funtion to determine if it is an A-, A, or A+, then insert accordingly. If it can be done by writing "return A;" as well, then that is just something that I am unaware of... Thanks everyone.